# facebook login using casper

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, facebook, casperjs

I am trying to log in to Facebook using casper. My program is as follows:

```
var casper=require("casper").create({
clientScripts:["C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python\jsfiles\jquery.min.js"],
verbose:true,
logLevel: 'debug'
});

var x =require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36');

phantom.cookiesEnabled=true;


var fs=require('fs');
var cookies=JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies);
fs.write('cookies.txt',cookies,644);

casper.start("https://www.facebook.com",function(){

   this.echo(this.getTitle());
}).viewport(1200,1000);


casper.wait(5000,function(){
    casper.capture('test1.png')
});

casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="pass"]'),function(){
this.thenEvaluate(function(){
   $('#email').val("");
   $('#pass').val(" ");
});
});

casper.wait(5000,function(){
    casper.capture('test2.png')
});
casper.then(function(){
casper.click(x('//*[@id="loginbutton"]'));
});

casper.wait(5000,function(){
    casper.capture('test3.png')
});
casper.run();
```

The above program returns completely, but the test2.png doesn't show any data in the email and password text boxes.  Moreover, test3.png returns "enter a valid email".

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an error in your javascript!

`$('#email').val("");` sets the field with id `email` to an empty string!

if you want to retrieve the value of a jQuery-Field do it like this:

`$('#email').val();`

[This](http://api.jquery.com/val/) might help you if you have more problems with jQuery